# Get Method Name in TypeScript class

Tags: typescript, metadata

Is there a way to get the method/function name in a TypeScript class?

The following TypeScript code aims to print the class name and the method name during runtime. The class name works well using `this.constructor.name`, but how do I get the method name?

```
export class MyClass {
    public myMethod() {
        console.log('Class name: '  + this.constructor.name);
        console.log('Method name: ' + XXX);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `this.myMethod.name`?

Comment: Doesn't help much. If I address `this.myMethod` I already know the name. I want to get the name during runtime similar to `this.name`.

Comment: In runtime you also know the name of the method - just look a few lines above.

Comment: I am looking for a generic way. If I address the method directly, I already have the name. What I want to do is create a method / function that uses the class name and method name for logging purposes.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't really support this, at least not in a standards compliant way.  Where are you logging this stuff?  If it's the console, you may want to consider [`console.trace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Stack_traces) instead of trying to hand-roll your own dynamic stack analysis.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYTgCgB4C5FioDuimAlIgLwB8iAhmAJ4UDeAsAFCLeLBwBOpADaooiALaI4wRAHkARgCt0UAHQBzUbKJgACvzgAHVPyiMAcnXGoAzjlWGDUOGeNlWnHl8QwZmSZSBiABEGGA2UPwg0ALBFGGwYCCoANye3twiYob4DIxUiNgOTi6MxgDa4gC6aVwZPn6uqNKIhogAhEHBoJCwCHGICTBJqekZRY4upRXVBT3Q8EiYqit0-Oo2uUwedfU8UAAWMDaqECD8ALKiB3DIBeK1e15ZiPyiBYaqdIaGQoyYh2OABp6OsbGRHk9uICTmdLtdbgUAG5wGB3AAMkKhbyg5yQOKx3gAvmNECSOOSIEI6DYbIgLowAMLU2mIdi7QbnK6HW4AfnwEX4w3UhPEjG5N2Q5DZpK8YRscBEqiEcHUmAA5MyaXSwFZUPh1YgANSIGGnBCC6LOfiqXXWCGynjyxWoZWqjXWHl3Q0ms1wiW3B0c8nktAYTAMrW0oOEEiRll2MiqMUBqVBoA)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encapsulate logging of `myMethod` invocation and others in a more generalized way (cross-cutting concern), you can use a [decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html):

```
function log<A extends any[], R>(
    target: Object,
    methodName: string,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: A) => R>) {
    let method = descriptor.value!; // this is the wrapped function
    descriptor.value = function (...args: A) {
        // instead of methodName, method.name works as well to get its name
        console.log("Calling", methodName, "with", args, "from", target.constructor.name)
        return method.apply(target, args);
    }
}

class MyClass {
    @log
    public myMethod() { }

    @log
    public myMethod2(s: string) { return 42 }
}

new MyClass().myMethod() // Calling myMethod with Array [] from MyClass
new MyClass().myMethod2("foo") // Calling myMethod2 with Array [ "foo" ] from MyClass
```

Here is a [sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=86#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGzgcwDwEFEFMAeUuYAJgM6ICGYAngNoC6ANIgEoB8AFALABQiAxFEoAnNLigAuRAHkARgCtc0Jn0GIAthIAWcEgDlKW6WSgiYYNKv6CSuMhHMAHKHBHSAKjSe4SABRE4HxEoGgARe0cYFzcMTgA6RNE0MmksAEpEAF52NnZMgG81QWQJTR09bMQ7B2dXEXiAN0pkEFwAQgBuRAB6HqFtGAohgdxEAHcRSicfEkRQSFgEYoEaqJiG5taxrPnwaHgkBKSxVMQMxCKbdQE+xAtTXEo5uGByqF0DI1wWLQ+9eJgb4TNwAawolAo41wyGQQjgiHEUHuUAoQK0KxuEAQZDgpXiqDQnAARABhFrICxoYm-CpfLQsYnjGAfGlUU6M4CBDRs4RiCTxbFgUwiEDQNyA77pTHqEQSEAiJB-T7xaZOZA0Th8pEsZJkdKdTEAXz4Jt4fAgyEhFAAsjRSVayBQruoAAKEzFOEBySkQTQ0G10ziFRBmzHu9Ce72+-2B-4kABMnDOIqpIblUAVSAALAnQ6a+HwwLhxog7Q7rcH4hoA0HMndybCqbG6RMWdpziIpjREIx5tyy-bHWQiyXBxWnVWa3HPknicA4HBifX+o3KZYW-G88yPp3u73EPPF8TEAx+3ANOPh0A). Be aware that this feature isn't stable yet and has to be enabled with [`experimentalDecorators`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) compiler option.

Answer (score 0):

If running in node, you can use [caller-callsite](https://github.com/sindresorhus/caller-callsite) this way:

```js
allerCallsite().getMethodName();
```

which returns:

```js
"myMethod"
```

Comment: BTW, on the browser you can use [error-stack-parser](https://github.com/stacktracejs/error-stack-parser): ```ErrorStackParser.parse(new Error());```.